# Simple file sharing using online file storage

Tags: file-sharing

Most of the popular online file hosting services require additional software to perform simple operations with files. E.g. you can't wget or rsync files from Amazon S3. On the other hand maintaining your own file share requires administering and you have to worry about security, data integrity, etc. by yourself. **Isn't there a simple online file hosting service which allows you to use wget, rsync, robocopy and other common tools?**

Comment: Maybe this helps for e.g. Dropbox:
http://superuser.com/a/470706

Comment: No, dropbox does everything behind scene AFAIR, it doesn't allow you rsync. And speed is quite low. But thanks for pointing out on superuser site.